# OSX - Not enough disk space to copy file

Tags: finder, external-disk, error, disk-space

I've been having issues with my Corsair keyboard and the first step given to me by support was to try updating the firmware. After plugging in the keyboard with the reset button held, it shows up as an external drive. When trying to copy over the firmware file using Finder, I would get an error along the lines of "file cannot be copied because there is not enough disk space". The file was the same size as the listed amount of free space on the external drive so I expected this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to copy over the file by using the terminal. If you hit command + space and search for `terminal`, you will open the `terminal` app. There you can type `ls /Volumes` to list the connect devices. For me this was `CRP DISABLD`. Then `cd` into the volume `cd /Volumes/CRP\ DISABLD` (use a backslash to escape any spaces). You can use `tab` to complete the name of the Volume if you start typing the beginning of it. Then use `mv` or `cp` to copy the file over: `mv ~/Downloads/STRAGE_ISP_V205.bin .` (the `.` means the directory you're currently in). In my case all the commands were:

```
➜  ~ ls /Volumes
➜  ~ cd /Volumes/CRP\ DISABLD
➜  CRP DISABLD mv ~/Downloads/STRAFE_ISP_V205.bin .
mv: ./STRAFE_ISP_V205 (1).bin: unable to move extended attributes and ACL from /Users/monroe/Downloads/STRAFE_ISP_V205 (1).bin: No space left on device
```

After moving the file over, `mv` showed the warning that it was unable to copy over the `extended attributes and ACL` from the original file. I believe this is what Finder was also trying to do and why the copy failed when using Finder